# Error: Query with id 'DAXSecurityUsersAndRoles' does not exist. How to resolve this?

Tags: reporting-services, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, ssrs-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I am trying to run a report in Dynamics AX
"Menu/Sys Admin/Reports/Security/Roles and Users Attached List" which is throwing me below error

Query with id 'DAXSecurityUsersAndRoles' does not exist.

Anybody faced this before? What to do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This menu item is not standard and must be your customization. Check your XPO import.

Comment: I think its custom one. I got rid of this error once i imported Query which is available in another xpo. Thanks.